# Pythonのモジュールを用いた特徴量抽出のためのプログラムでエラーが出る問題について

Tags: python, 機械学習, jupyter-notebook, 自然言語処理

## 前提・実現したいこと

言語処理100本ノックの「[6章機械学習　51. 特徴量抽出](https://nlp100.github.io/ja/ch06.html)」の問題について、回答でどの部分を修正したらいいかわからないです。

Qiita記事「[言語処理100本ノック 2020 第6章: 機械学習の51](https://qiita.com/nymwa/items/774ca6c542c1eaff160d)」に掲載されていた回答のまま、jupyter notebookでプログラムを実行しています。

## エラーメッセージ

モジュール`spacy`はインストールしましたが、

```
Can't find model 'en'.
```

とエラーが出て、何が問題でエラーが引き起こされているのか見当がつかない状態です。

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-e9ad3573f268> in <module>
      4 import nltk
      5 
----> 6 nlp = spacy.load('en')
      7 stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer(language='english')
      8 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py in load(name, **overrides)
     28     if depr_path not in (True, False, None):
     29         deprecation_warning(Warnings.W001.format(path=depr_path))
---> 30     return util.load_model(name, **overrides)
     31 
     32 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.4/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py in load_model(name, **overrides)
    167     elif hasattr(name, "exists"):  # Path or Path-like to model data
    168         return load_model_from_path(name, **overrides)
--> 169     raise IOError(Errors.E050.format(name=name))
    170 
    171 

OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. 
It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

## コード

```py
#51 特徴量抽出
import re
import spacy
import nltk

nlp = spacy.load('en')
stemmer = nltk.stem.snowball.SnowballStemmer(language='english')

def tokenize(x):
    x = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', x)
    x = nlp.make_doc(x) #nlp(x)は遅い tokenizer以外も走るので
    x = [stemmer.stem(doc.lemma_.lower()) for doc in x]
    return x

tokenized_train = [[cat, tokenize(line)] for cat, line in train]
tokenized_valid = [[cat, tokenize(line)] for cat, line in valid]
tokenized_test = [[cat, tokenize(line)] for cat, line in test]

# 出現頻度を数える
counter = Counter([
    token
    for _, tokens in tokenized_train
    for token in tokens
])

# 高頻度・低頻度の語を取り除く
vocab = [
    token
    for token, freq in counter.most_common()
    if 2 < freq < 300
]

len(vocab)
```

## 開発環境

jupyter notebook 6.0.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

この記事が該当すると思われます。
エラーメッセージのように、モデルデータが無いことが原因なのでしょう。

[spacy.load('en')が実行できない](https://teratail.com/questions/173701)
Q:

> Jupyter　notebookで下記のコードを実行すると、次のようなエラーがでます。
>
> ```
> import spacy
> en_nlp = spacy.load('en')
>
> OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'en'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
> ```

A:

> モデルのダウンロードが済んでないことが原因のエラーですね。
> このコマンドでモデルをダウンロードして再度同じコードを実行すればエラーが解消します。
>
> ```
> python3 -m spacy download en
> ```
>
> 参考: [GitHub - explosion/spaCy:  Industrial-strength Natural Language Processing (NLP) with Python and Cython](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy)

---

> このコードで出来そうですね。
>
> ```
> en_nlp = spacy.load('/path/to/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0')
> ```
>
> https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1663

---

> パスもやってみてうまくいきませんでしたが、下記のぺージを参考にコマンドを入力したら上手くいきました！！！
>
> https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/1721